# How to save data to file in html (HTML ONLY)

Tags: html, forms

I am developing my own website, in my code I have a few forms (shown below) I want to save the data of these forms to a .txt file. Therefore I can view them later on. I would like to only use html, for I am new at the language (only started a few days ago, website is for testing only.)

```
<form>
<code>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="1-day">1 Day Span - 50 USD</br>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="2-day">2 Day Span - 100 USD</br>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="3-day">3 Day Span - 150 USD</br>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="4-day">4 Day Span - 200 USD</br>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="5-day">5 Day Span - 250 USD</br>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="6-day">6 Day Span - 300 USD</br>
    <input type="radio" name="span" value="7-day">7 Day Span - 350 USD</br>
</code>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not possible with only HTML.

Comment: What's with the `<code>` tags?

Comment: @Turnip The website has a certain look to it, it is not your normal website, I want it to have to coded text like look on the display, the code tag allows text to have a altered font thats looks like code.

Comment: You should be using CSS to style your website. The code tag is for displaying, well...code. Like the block of code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with html alone. You will need to use either:

1. Javascript
2. Server-side code (PHP, ASP.NET, etc)

Based on your question, I don't think you have a full understanding of how web programming (client-server) works. I would recommend reading some tutorials such as these:

Server-side programming: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction

Client-side programming: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Introduction_to_Web_development

Answer (score 0):

HTML is for information display only. Any programming logic either requires a client language like Javascript or server language like PHP or ASP.

Answer (score 0):

The way you worded your question is confusing. Not getting into the code and whether its correct or not, if you just want to save the form to a text file, you can; just change the extension to .txt Or just keep it as html.